# Only the last item added works (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

I have a list of items and when I click the modal it opens wherein you could change details. So, I have a select box that when an option is selected there will be an HTML appended, but my problem is the select box thingy or maybe my jquerycode is only working on the last item added.

Here is my HTML/JS/CSS code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.set').click(function(){
              $('.askq').removeAttr('hidden');
              $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            });
            $('.mode').change(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
               var val = $(".mode option:selected").val();
               var div = document.getElementById('address');
               console.log(val);
              if(val=="Delivery"){
              div.innerHTML="<label style='float:center; font-size:15px; color:black'><b>&nbsp;Delivery Address:</b></label><input type='text' name='d_address' class='form-control has-success' id='defadd' style='width:250px' value='{{$order->location}}'><input type='checkbox' class='defaultadd' id='defaultadd' checked>&nbsp;Use default address";
              }
           else {
               div.innerHTML="<label><label style='float:center; font-size:15px; color:black'><b>&nbsp;Pick-Up Address:</b></label>&nbsp;<label>{{$order->c_location}}</label><input type='hidden' name='p_address' value='{{$order->c_location}}'>";
               }
        
          $(".defaultadd").change(function(){
          if ($(".defaultadd").is(":checked")){
              // $select.removeAttr('disabled');
               $('#defadd').val('{{$order->location}}');
          }else{
              $('#defadd').val('');
              $('#defadd').attr('placeholder', 'Please choose delivery location')
             // $select.attr('disabled','disabled');
          }
           });
        });
            });
```

```css
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48403772/only-the-last-item-added-works-jquery#
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="fullCalModal1" class="modal fade pull-left" 
  style="align-content: center">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="float:left; margin-right: 1500px">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span 
             aria-hidden="true">×</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span>
              </button>
               <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title" style="color: #4caf50">
                <b>{{$order->title}}</b></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body col-md-12"> 
              <div class="col-md-6">
                 <center><button type="button" class="btn btn-flat btn-success 
                  btn-md set" style="margin-bottom:50px;">SET DETAILS</button>
                 </center>
              <div class="askq" hidden>
                <label style="float:center; font-size:15px; color:black">
                  <b>&nbsp;Mode of Delivery:</b></label>
                  <select name="mode" class="mode form-control" id="mode">
                    <option value="Delivery">Delivery</option>
                    <option value="Pickup">Pick up</option>
                  </select>
             <div class="address" id="address"></div>
                   <label style="float:center; font-size:15px; color:black">
                    <b>&nbsp;Do you have any specifications?</b></label>
                  <input type='text' name="spec" class='form-control has-
                  success' style='width:250px'>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-
                  dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><a id="eventUrl" 
                style="color:white" target="_blank">Save Changes</a></button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div id="fullCalModal2" class="modal fade pull-left" 
  style="align-content: center">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="float:left; margin-right: 1500px">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span 
             aria-hidden="true">×</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span>
              </button>
               <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title" style="color: #4caf50">
                <b>{{$order->title}}</b></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body col-md-12"> 
              <div class="col-md-6">
                 <center><button type="button" class="btn btn-flat btn-success 
                  btn-md set" style="margin-bottom:50px;">SET DETAILS</button>
                 </center>
              <div class="askq" hidden>
                <label style="float:center; font-size:15px; color:black">
                  <b>&nbsp;Mode of Delivery:</b></label>
                  <select name="mode" class="mode form-control" id="mode">
                    <option value="Delivery">Delivery</option>
                    <option value="Pickup">Pick up</option>
                  </select>
             <div class="address" id="address"></div>
                   <label style="float:center; font-size:15px; color:black">
                    <b>&nbsp;Do you have any specifications?</b></label>
                  <input type='text' name="spec" class='form-control has-
                  success' style='width:250px'>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-
                  dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><a id="eventUrl" 
                style="color:white" target="_blank">Save Changes</a></button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Can anyone here have a solution for this?

Comment: Both options seem to be working in your example. It changes when I select pick up, and again when I choose delivery. Do you mean it's not changing if you select delivery from the start? If so, it's because of the `.change` listener and the fact that delivery is the default option, so "selecting" it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @mcon yes the select and pick-up is working, but my problem is this for instance I have 2 items in added so when I tried changing the details of item1 the select box is not working, while on item2 it is working. So it is only working on the last item added.

Comment: It seems to be working but i think your problem is that you want the have "Delivery" fields visible by default. If that's the case have a look at this. https://jsfiddle.net/8hpb5g64/1/

Comment: @naning14 Unless I'm missing something, I can only set the details for one item in your snippet. Can you update the code so there are multiple items to set details for?

Comment: @Lidaranis Ohh okay thanks for help btw, but i have a different problem. So, my problem is:  for instance I have 2 items in added so when I tried changing the details of item1 the select box is not working, while on item2 it is working. So it is only working on the last item added

Comment: @mcon Ohh yeah I forgot! Sorry. Already edited the code!

Comment: @mcon and yes there are multiple items because it being loop from database.

Comment: i think i see what you mean. Replace  var div = document.getElementById('address');   with var div = $(this).parent().find('.address')[0]; and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Lidaranis it now working, but there's a problem. the item1 is only getting the first option which is delivery. And i added another item which item3 and its the same as item1, only item2 is working well.

Comment: @naning14 just to be sure we are on the same page. When you say "item1 is only getting the first option" you mean that in the <select> for the first item the only <option> is "Delivery". Right?

Comment: @naning14 There's still only one item in your example since SO doesn't have access to your database. Can you hardcode two items into the example so we can understand exactly what the problem is?

Comment: @Lidaranis yes it is.

Comment: @mcon edited the code.

Comment: @naning14 this should do it https://jsfiddle.net/aqunmLyo/   EDIT: I removed some of the buttons in order to make it easier to follow. but i am sure you can add them back :)

Comment: Omg!! Thank you for saving my night. :))) It is now working welll!. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello. I know it's late, but i hope you could help me. I just found out that whenever i open a modal and clicks the "set details" button and then when i open another modal it will direct me to the div (hidden).